# jumbledString: Given a string s and a number n, write a function that concatenates the even-indexed chars to the front

Tags: java, string, big-o, stringbuilder

Given a string s and a number n, write a function that concatenates the even-indexed chars to the front, odd-indexed chars to the back, n times.
Examples:

- s = "Wow Example!"`
- result = "WwEapeo xml!"

Bellow is my response to this question now I need to optimize this solution so that it runs in O(n). Please help guys.

```java
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String wordToJumble = "Wow Example!";
        Long numberOfTimes = 1L;
        jumbledString( wordToJumble,numberOfTimes);
    }

    public static String jumbledString(String s,Long n){
        StringBuilder sbEven = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbOdd = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder s2= new StringBuilder(s);
        char[] word = s.toCharArray();
        if(n>0) {
            while (n > 0) {
                n--; 
                sbEven.setLength(0);
                sbOdd.setLength(0); 
                for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        sbEven.append(word[i]);
                    } else {
                        sbOdd.append(word[i]);
                    }
                }
                s2 = sbEven.append(sbOdd);
                word = s2.toString().toCharArray();

            }
            System.out.println(s2);
        }else{
            System.out.println(s2);
        }
        return s2.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just go char by char and add to the result `sbEven` or `sbOdd` where appropriate. After that, `append()` n times to result string. And you can use `charAt(int)` method instead of casting your string to `char[]`.

That solution is in `O(n)`, but notice, that `n` is not your `numberOfTimes`. It's string lenght.

```java
public static String jumbledString(String s, long n) {
    StringBuilder sbEven = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sbOdd = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            sbEven.append(s.charAt(i));
        } else {
            sbOdd.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result.append(sbEven);
        result.append(sbOdd);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Or without the second loop, you can use `repeat()` method for `String` (I assumed `n` is `long`):

```java
return result.toString().repeat((int) n);
```

Comment: Thank you guys This solution is great however we need to be able to jumble the same string a number of times and not concatenate it as it is what happens when I implement this   n times.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand, could you provide more details, what exactly do you need? After each jumble the string can change?

Comment: So the String must be jumbled n times.  So since Strings are immutable I use Char Array to achieve this. The original code I supplied at the top achieves this but now I need to optimize the solution so that it runs in O(n)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String wordToJumble = "Wow Example!";
    Long numberOfTimes = 9L;
    jumbledString(wordToJumble, numberOfTimes);
}

public static String jumbledString(String s, Long n) {
    StringBuilder sbEven = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sbOdd = new StringBuilder();
    char[] word = s.toCharArray();
    if (n > 0) {
            for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                word = newJumble(word, sbEven, sbOdd);
            }
    }
    System.out.println(word);
    return word.toString();
}

private static char[] newJumble(char[] s, StringBuilder sbEven, StringBuilder sbOdd) {
    sbEven.setLength(0);
    sbOdd.setLength(0);
    StringBuilder result;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            sbEven.append(s[i]);
        } else {
            sbOdd.append(s[i]);
        }
    }
    result = sbEven.append(sbOdd);
    return result.toString().toCharArray();
}
```

}

Comment: With this approach I was able to separate the nested loop and created another private method to call the second loop.  One method sets up the structure of the String and the other one controls how many time the String is jumbled. I use Char Arrays because they are mutable and easier to manage than Strings.